# www 301 redirect for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7

I am trying to redirect http://example.com/abc to http://www.example.com/abc . I have .htaccess in root folder and sub-folder (abc) as well. I have tried " Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/abc/" and "RewriteBase ^(.*)/$ /abc" in sub-folder's htaccess. It said 'Page could not be redirected properly. How and where should i write condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to redirect non-www to www for the /abc folder.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^abc http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, page is opening with www. but when opened with out www its not redirecting to www. i have tried R=301 , but still when opened without www it not redirecting to www.